# value of input from PHP postback

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
<form>
   .............
    <?php
    if (!isset($_FILES['before']['name'] || !isset($_FILES['after']['name']) 
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Show Image">'
    else 
        echo '<input type="submit" value="Upload">'
    ?>
</form>
```

in my postback how do I check whether it's one or the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You give both submit buttons the same `name` and then check its value in the postback with...

```
$_POST['submit_name']
```